# Video cropping w/ Matrix android java

Tags: java, android, matrix, video, crop

The task is to crop video by given points(like rectangle) and display the cropped video.
The [code](https://github.com/DablSi/Screen) works with cropping the [first halh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49MJc.jpg) of video(0, 0, videoWidth/2, videoHeight). But when i tryed to display the second one(videoWidth/2, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight), [that is what was displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr0P2.png).

The video is displayed on TextureView inside FrameLayout.

The part, that doesn't work:

```
private void updateTextureViewSize(int ax, int ay, int bx, int by) {
    float scaleX;
    float scaleY;

    //proportions between screen and frame dimensions
    scaleX = mVideoWidth / mDisplayWidth;
    scaleY = mVideoHeight / mDisplayHeight;

    float scaleRegionW = mVideoWidth / Math.abs(ax - bx);
    float scaleRegionH = mVideoHeight / Math.abs(ay - by);
    float scaleRegion = scaleRegionW < scaleRegionH ? scaleRegionW : scaleRegionH;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    if (scaleX > scaleY) {
        matrix.setScale(scaleRegion / scaleY, scaleRegion);
        matrix.postTranslate(-ax * (int) scaleRegion / scaleY, -ay * scaleRegion / scaleY);
    } else {
        matrix.setScale(scaleRegion, scaleRegion / scaleX);
        matrix.postTranslate(-ax * scaleRegion / scaleX, -ay * scaleRegion / scaleX);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) mDisplayWidth, (int) mDisplayHeight));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found by [Dmitry Yacenko](https://github.com/d-yacenko).
The full [code](https://github.com/DablSi/Screen/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/ducks/screen/VideoAssetActivity.java).

An easy way to crop video by *given points* (ax, ay, bx, xy) is:

```
    float scaleX = mDisplayWidth / mVideoWidth, scaleY = mDisplayHeight / mVideoHeight; 
    //proportions between screen and frame dimensions
    float scale = mDisplayHeight / Math.abs(by - ay);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.setScale(scale / scaleX, scale / scaleY);
    //scaling video
    matrix.postTranslate(-scale * ax, -scale * ay);
    //move video, so the needed part of it will be displayed properly
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) mDisplayWidth, (int) mDisplayHeight));
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    //updating the Texture view
```